# How to add auto create feature to custom taxonomy_term field while creating custom entity

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms, entities

I created a custom module which has an custom entity.
I added base field term_id to it using below code

```
$fields['term_id'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('entity_reference')
    ->setLabel(t('Category'))
    ->setDescription(t('Default Category.'))
    ->setRevisionable(TRUE)
    ->setSetting('target_type', 'taxonomy_term')
    ->setSetting('handler', 'default:taxonomy_term')
    ->setSetting('handler_settings', [
            'target_bundles' => ['question_category' => 'question_category']
        ]
    )
    ->setTranslatable(TRUE)
    ->setDisplayOptions('view', array(
        'label' => 'hidden',
        'type' => 'author',
        'weight' => 0,
    ))
    ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
        'type' => 'entity_reference_autocomplete',
        'weight' => 5,
        'settings' => array(
            'match_operator' => 'CONTAINS',
            'size' => '60',
            'autocomplete_type' => 'tags',
            'placeholder' => '',
        ),
    ))
    ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
    ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);
```

I have a YAML file taxonomy.vocabulary.question_category.yml, 
which create question_category vocabulary, I can see it in admin too.

But when I try to add a new text in it. I get an error
There are no entities matching ||new enitity title||

I want user to create terms and add it to question_category taxonomy.

Please suggest, what might be the error.

--

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I did it using below handler setting

setSetting('handler_settings', ['target_bundles' => ['question_sub_category' => 'question_sub_category'], **'auto_create' => TRUE**])